# Output abnormal .. WHY?

Tags: javascript

I have many days that I can not run this script!

```js
var b = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]; 
var a = (function(){ 
  var W = []; 
  for(var k in b){ 
    W[W.length] = { 
      index : k, 
      fx : function(){ 
        console.log(k); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  return W; 
})(); 
 
console.log(a); 
for(var j = 0; a[j]; j++)a[j].fx();
```

Because it does not produce as OUTPUT numerical sequence **987654321**?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function `fx` that you create references the variable `var k`. They don't save the current value of `k`, only a reference to `k`. This means that when you run the functions, after the for loop has finished, the value of `k` is now `8`, and they all print that.

Once way to avoid this, and give each function its own variable/value, is to change `var k` to `let k` (available since ECMAScript 6). See [`let` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

```js
var b = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]; 
var a = (function(){ 
  var W = []; 
  for (let k in b) { 
    W[W.length] = { 
      index : k, 
      fx : function(){ 
        console.log(k); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  return W; 
})(); 
 
for(var j = 0; a[j]; j++)
  a[j].fx();
```

Comment: Uh .. Thanks! I noticed that **LET** is only supported by the latest browsers. how can I do to increase compatibility with **older browsers**?

Comment: See [the accepted answer on the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1848578) for several solutions.